# Pantalla negra en "ubuntu 20.04 virtualbox" después que inicio

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Estaba trabajando en ubuntu 20.4, en específico estaba usando buildozer para generar una apk, cuando me aparece un mensaje de quedan 0mb de espacio en el sistema.

Recordé que solo le había dejado 13gb de espacio de disco duro, así que me salí de la máquina virtual (apague la máquina virtual), fui al `cmd` a ejecutar la instrucción:

```
voxmanage modifyhd "D:Ubuntu/ubuntu.vdi"  --resize 23000
```

Posteriormente, me marcó que estaba correcto, así que intenté abrir mi máquina virtual. Todo iba bien hasta que vi que de repente se ponía oscura la pantalla y cada vez que trato de encenderla, se queda en negro.

Éste es el error:

```
/dev/sda5: recovering journal  
/dev/sda5: clean, 243794/806256 files, 3117287/3219968 blocks  
[   12.645361] [drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message.  
[   12.645931] [drm:vmw_host_log [vmwgfx]] *ERROR* Failed to send host log message.
```

Mostrando este error al iniciar:

[image: al iniciar muestra ese error]

Luego carga bien pero posteriormente se queda en negro:

[image: carga bien al inicio pero posteriormente se queda en negro]

De esta manera:

[image: se queda de esta manera]

¿Por qué puede estar ocurriendo este error? ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo??? Tengo exactamente el mismo problema y no encuentro solucion.

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo? tengo el mismo problema